# How Do I Capture Template Events in Meteor v1.0?

Tags: html, templates, meteor, meteor-helper

I think this is not the problem of Meteor.js,
but I have no idea which categories is appropriate for this question.

I used to use  tag to get the events with the other component.
i.e.

```
<a href="#" name="someName"><i>...</i><button>...</button></a>
```

and then I handled this events on the template side,

```
Template.name.events
  'click [name=someName]': (e, tmpl) ->
    // do actions
```

But from the V1.0, this approach doesn't work as I used before.
The events couldn't reach to the Template events methods, so I can't do my actions in it.

I know this approach would be not the correct way to be used like this,
but this was really useful and my project was already made by this way a lot.

Is there another idea to be done this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So with

```
Template.name.events
```

You have a template named 'name'?

This is bad practice. You should avoid naming templates (or anything for that matter) things that could conflict with the javascript APIs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name . 'Template' is a function, if you simply type Template.name in your browser console it will probably return something like "". Basically your Template.name.anything isn't working correctly.

I tried making a new project with just a template named 'name'

```
<template name="name"> ... </template>
```

There is nothing wrong with your event selector. So the easy fix is just rename the template.

If your template is not named name then your events helper should take the form

```
Template.<template_name>.events
```